# Conditional unique constraint for DB2

Tags: db2

So as many of you will know, in DB2 you can say

```
   ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE
  ADD CONSTRAINT NEWID UNIQUE(EMPNO,HIREDATE)
```

Can you say something like

```
   ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE
  ADD CONSTRAINT NEWID UNIQUE(EMPNO,HIREDATE,ACTIVE = 'Y')
```

I only care about the constraint if the row is active. I looks like you can do this in MSSQL but not DB2... Err, grumble grumble.

Comment: It depends on the release and/or "flavor" of DB2. With DB2 for i at 6.1 and later, you can `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX x ... WHERE search-condition` in order to have conditional uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably too late for the OP, but I had a similar problem and found the solution here: [Emulating partial indexes in DB2](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-11/seven-surprising-findings-about-DB2#blog-db2intro-partialidx)

The code for creating a unique index on column `empno` could look like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON employee (CASE WHEN active = 'Y' THEN empno ELSE NULL END) EXCLUDE NULL KEYS;
```

and accordingly for both columns `empno` and `hiredate`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON employee (CASE WHEN active = 'Y' THEN empno ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN active = 'Y' THEN hiredate ELSE NULL END) EXCLUDE NULL KEYS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike several other DBMS, DB2 does not support partial indexes.

So I don't think you will be able to implement this in DB2